# Dropdown selected value incorrect In mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc.grid/webgrid with dropdownlist. On dropdown select change event I am getting only first row of dropdown selected value. When Selecting second row dropdown then getting value of first dropdown only which is incorrect.

Can anyone help me on this.

```
function fillAmount(){
var ddlmonthId = $("#ddlmonth").val();


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @webGrid.GetHtml(
        htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
        columns: webGrid.Columns(
                 webGrid.Column("key_cit", "key_cit"),
                 webGrid.Column("key_date", "key_date"),
                 webGrid.Column("key_veh_license", "key_veh_license"),
                  webGrid.Column(format: @<text>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlmonth", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.ddlmonth, new { onchange = "fillAmount(this)", @class = ".we" });
                </text>),
                 webGrid.Column("AmountPayPlan", "Country"),
                 //  webGrid.Column("Country", "Country"),
                 webGrid.Column(null, null, format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Select", null, null, new { @class = "select" })</text>)
      ))

}
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html.

Comment: can you explain in more detail or help me to fix the above code

Comment: Does every row get a `DropDownList("ddlmonth")?` If so then what Stephen says is probably the reason. To clarify: *every DropDownList in the grid* must have a *unique ID* if you want to use it like that. You can't use the same id `ddlmonth` for every one of them.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("ddlmonth", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.ddlmonth, new { id = "", @class = "we" });` and `$('.we').change(function() { var ddlmonthId = $(this).val(); });`

Comment: No it is not working . I am getting value as Undefined

Comment: @Mahtabr you'll have to show us exactly what you did and where the "undefined" error occurs, because the code Stephen gave you should work. Perhaps you didn't implement it correctly.

Comment: Thanks Stephen ,It is working fine.